# Glycocylation or glycosylation?

Tags: proteins

I came across a few sources that refer to glycocylation. Is this the same as glycosylation?

See for instance [page 237](https://books.google.se/books?id=BiktDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA237&lpg=PA237&dq=%22glycocylation%22&source=bl&ots=6orGBbqCBU&sig=ACfU3U11litz76c8ZB2SHc9mLqQCLXFedg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGp6yN6_boAhXaAxAIHRALCtgQ6AEwAnoECAsQKw#v=onepage&q=%22glycocylation%22&f=false), or the abstract [in this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19764807).

```
"glycocylation" - 1210 search results on google  
"glycosylation" - 5.98m search results on google
```

Comment: Ever heard of typographical errors or mistranslation from languages where the consonant C is pronounced like an English S? At 1 in 6000, that is the conclusion I would have drawn.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, glycocylation is same as glycosylation. You can check out following links which explain glycocylaion same as post translational modification named glycosylation.

https://www.semanticscholar.org/author/Haudhiya/93411308

https://grantome.com/grant/NIH/R01-DA004166-05

https://quizlet.com/137217422/lecture-10-a-biochem-final-flash-cards/

https://books.google.com/books?id=3RbT3cpdCc0C&pg=PA508&lpg=PA508&dq=glycocylation&source=bl&ots=qIwbK6-ZdP&sig=ACfU3U18W_rG0D53R67_fzAywtMXGye5NA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKrvfJp_foAhW3knIEHWLVB8gQ6AEwFnoECGQQQw#v=onepage&q=glycocylation&f=false

Comment: None of these references, except maybe obscurely the quizlet, do much of anything to support the equivalence of the two words.  The abstracts of the first two just mention one of the words, and the full papers are in Indonesian or unavailable, respectively.